# Using Summernote editor with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, summernote

I included the following in my html's body:

```
{{> editor}}
```

and the following template

```
<template name="editor">
    <div id="summernote">Hello Summernote</div>
</template>
```

In my javascript code I have the following:

```
Template.editor.onRendered(function()
{
 this.$('.summernote').summernote();
});
```

I see the following instead of the full blown summernote rich text editor. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: if you do `$('.summernote').summernote();` from browser console everything works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element has an `id` of 'summernote', but your selector is looking for an element with a `class` or 'summernote'

Change your selector to `$('#summernote')` like this:

```
Template.editor.onRendered(function() {
  this.$('#summernote').summernote();
}
```